# Error when passing a function in the React data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a function on the sectionOne, then call sectionOne from another component but I am getting an error.

```
Error: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {Home} from './home';

export const appTabBar = {
    sectionOne: function sectionOne() {
        return (
            <>
                <Home />
            </>
        );
    },
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const DrawerSection = props => {
    const {sectionOne} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <div>{sectionOne}</div>
        </>
    );
};
DrawerSection.propTypes = {
    sectionOne: PropTypes.any,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to render `sectionOne` as a React component, and [user-defined components must be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). You can either rename  `sectionOne` in the file where it is declared or assign it to a variable in the file where it is used:

```
export const DrawerSection = props => {
    const {sectionOne: SectionOne} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <div><SectionOne /></div>
        </>
    );
};
```